# Create a zip file from a directory, but not his fullpath

Tags: python

Im trying to create a zipfile with the content of a folder ( some dirs and files ) using the code belllow:

```
import zip,os

path = "c:\\tester\\folderToZip"
zip = zipfile.ZipFile("zippedFolder.zip", "w")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        zip.write(os.path.join(root, file))
zip.close()
```

But after the code runs, when i check the zip file, the zip file, instead having the content of the folder "folderToZip" ( ex: f1,f2,f2, a.txt,b.txt,c.txt ) it have the full path of the variable path.

So, the question is, how can i create a zipfile based on a folder content, but not his fullpath ?

Answer (score 2):

[`write`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.write) takes a second optional parameter `arcname`, which when specified will provide the name for the file stored. Use that to specify the name you want.

If you only want the filename:

```
import zip,os

path = "c:\\tester\\folderToZip"
zip = zipfile.ZipFile("zippedFolder.zip", "w")
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    for file in files:
        filename = os.path.join(root, file)
        zip.write(filename, filename)
zip.close()
```

Comment: Hi, could you give an example of how could i use?

Comment: `zip.write(os.path.join(root, file), file)` is probably what you're after @Thales

Comment: @mata Hi, It worked im some way, but it added all the files from the directories, but ignored the dir structure. SO, instead adding c:\tester\folderToZip\f1\f2\f1f2.txt, it added f1f2.txt to the zip

Comment: @Thales - from your description I thougth that's what you ment. If you wann to keep the directory strcucture, you need to add that to arcname. updated my example.

Comment: @mata Hi, Now after running with the change i have the same result as before. Instead having on the zipfile the content  (f1,f2,f2, a.txt,b.txt,c.txt ) i have tester\folderToZip\f1, tester\folderToZip\f2 and so on.

Comment: Then just strip away the leading part.